# Angular 5 - equivalent to $interval from AngularJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, delay, repeat

I'm trying to find the equivalent of the `$interval` from AngularJS into Angular 5.

`$interval` will repeat a function call or a block a specified number of times with a delay in-between.
This is what I would like to do, written in AngularJS:

```
$interval(function() {
      myFunction(param1, param2)
      i++;
    }, delay, count);
```

Make abstraction of **i**, I'm using it for a different purpose.
How can this be achieved in Angular 5?
I already tried using **rxjs/Observable** but I can't seem to find a way to include both the delay and the run multiple times part.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6539

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may make use of the `timer` static method and `take` operator.

```
import {timer} from 'rxjs';
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';  

timer(yourDelay, 1000).pipe(
   take(yourCount)).subscribe(x=>{
    // do here whatever you want to do here
    })
```

I assumed you use RxJS 6.

Comment: Yes, I am using RxJS 6. But I don't have an Observable. Should I create a new one using Observable.create() ? Or I should have an existing one to use this approach?

Comment: If you do not have an observable, you may use timer static method (which creates an observable for you). Check the updated answer.

Comment: After using the timer this gave the expected result. Thank you for the solution and for the explanations.

Comment: Great and simple solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `interval` with `take` to control how many times you want to call your function.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

const delay = 1000; // every 1 sec
const count = 5; // process it 5 times

Observable.interval(delay).take(count).subscribe(() => {
  myFunction(param1, param2);
});
```

Comment: This gives me back 'Property interval does not exists on type Observable' at build time. I think this is caused by the version of RxJS. I am using RxJS 6.

Comment: @BogdanPușcașu it should still work even for v6, I've updated the answer, please try adding `import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use interval from rxjs

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = interval(1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This will emit new value after every 1 second

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this](http://musttoknow.com/call-service-particular-interval-time-angular-4/) tutorial for your query. its working fine in Angular 5 also.. I tried it and its given here simple way.

```
import { Observable } from “rxjs”;

import { IntervalObservable } from “rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable”;

import { TimerObservable } from “rxjs/observable/TimerObservable”;

import “rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile”;

Declare variable in class
export class MyComponent implements OnInit { 

private alive: boolean; 

}

In ngOnInit() function use below code to call service after particular interval of time
ngOnInit() {

IntervalObservable.create(10000)  .takeWhile(() => this.alive) 
// only fires when component is alive  

.subscribe(() => { this.yourService.getDataList()   
.subscribe(data => { this.agentData = data.json().result; console.log(this.agentData);   });
 });
}
```